# Authenticate *from* Firebase Cloud Functions to custom Node Server

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm having troubles to authenticate **from** Firebase Cloud Functions to a custom Node server.

**Background:**

I use a custom node + express server to receive calls from authenticated clients coming from our website. I can successfully verify their tokens using something like this:

```js
const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
const bearerToken = bearerHeader.split(' ')[1];
await admin.auth().verifyIdToken( bearerToken );
```

**What I need now:**

I need to call one of this endpoints but from a Cloud Function (not from an authenticated web client).

So, on the cloud function I'm calling:

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
      admin.initializeApp();  // regular initialization
const token = await admin.app().options.credential?.getAccessToken();
const config = { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token.id_token}` } };
await axios.post(url, body, config);
```

**The problem:**

The `token.id_token` field is missing from `getAccessToken()`:

```js
// token:
{
  access_token: 'ya29. ... ... ',
  expires_in: 3599,
  token_type: 'Bearer'
}
```

When locally run with other credentials (my user credentials when running `firebase functions:shell`, for example, or when setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to a service account credentials file) I do get an extra property `id_token` that I can use to authenticate. But when deployed and run on the Cloud Function, `id_token` property is empty.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

PS: an extra problem... the local test with a service account do include `id_token`, but when authenticating to the server `getAccessToken()` fails with:

```
Firebase ID token has incorrect "aud" (audience) claim. Expected "<project-id>" but got "<some-hash>.apps.googleusercontent.com".
```

Maybe both problems solve the same way. But the server does work properly to verify user tokens coming from a website.

**EDIT:**

I had to exchange the `access_token` for an `id_token`, for which I followed something similar to [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#generating_tokens_programmatically), with the `projectId` as audience.
Now the problem is about the issuer (iss) instead of the audience (aud):

```
Firebase ID token has incorrect "iss" (issuer) claim. Expected "https://securetoken.google.com/<project id>" but got "https://accounts.google.com".
```

I guess I could verify the token on the server using the same library, but then my web clients would have the same issuer problem

Comment: Can you try this [1][2] and check if it works for you.

[1]https://stackoverflow.com/a/67205708/15803365
[2]https://stackoverflow.com/a/65940148/15803365

Comment: Thank you @PriyashreeBhadra. After reading many similar problems, including those 2 you mention, I ended up solving the "iss" (issuer) mismatch by using the same issuer library on both, client and server. I used `google-auth-library`, though that's not exactly what I wanted because my other clients (real users through our website) were already authenticating using Firebase (which causes the "iss" mismatch if I don't use firebase on the server to verify the token). So I ended up just opening a different path for my could function to authenticate, before executing the rest of the same code.